# How to filter JSON data in angular by using filter

Tags: json, angularjs, filter

I am looking for good book or links to study to filter data from JSON to use in angular filter. Some complex data. Please, could someone help me on this.

Comment: This question is off topic, please have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic (point 4)

Comment: learn how to use `Array.prototype.filter()`

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$filter or in your template use something like ng-repeat="item in items | filter: { field: valueFromInput }" where field is a property of item and valueFromInput is some id from a textbox.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of filters more concentrate on custom directives, compare to filters it will improve the performance

Thank you,
Chaitanya